# Criei um aplicação no android studio mas quando instalo no telefone e jogo fica lenta

Tags: android

- Boa tarde, criei uma pequena aplicação e passei para o telefone para experimentar como rodava bem no meu telefone Dei aos meus amigos para ver se corria bem no telefone deles. Acabei por descobrir que em alguns fica lento e noutros rápido. Ficando mesmo lento em telefones de boa capacidade. Preciso de ajuda.

Codigo (Main_activity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button b_flip1;

Button b_flip2;

ImageView iv_coin1;

ImageView iv_coin2;
Random r;

Random r1;

int coinSide;

int coinSide1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    b_flip1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_flip1);
    b_flip2 = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.b_flip2);
    iv_coin1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_coin1);
    iv_coin2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_coin2);
    r = new Random();
    r1 = new Random();

    //codigo button 1 ............................................................................


    b_flip1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            coinSide = r.nextInt(7);

            if (coinSide == 0){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ummpt);

            } else if (coinSide == 1){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.doissspt);

            } else if (coinSide == 2){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.tressspt);


            }else if (coinSide == 3){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.quatrooopt);

            }else  if (coinSide == 4){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cincoopt);

            }else if (coinSide == 5){
                iv_coin1.setImageResource(R.drawable.seissspt);

            }


            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,360,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(1000);
            iv_coin1.startAnimation(rotate);

        }
    });



    //codigo button 2 .............................................................................


    b_flip2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            coinSide1 = r1.nextInt(7);

            if (coinSide1 == 0){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.seteept);

            } else if (coinSide1 == 1){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.oitoopt);

            } else if (coinSide1 == 2){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.noveept);


            }else if (coinSide1 == 3){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dezzpt);

            }else  if (coinSide1 == 4){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.onzeept);

            }else if (coinSide1 == 5){
                iv_coin2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dozeeept);

            }

            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,360,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(1000);
            iv_coin2.startAnimation(rotate);

        }
    });

}
```

}

.................................................................

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ummpt"
            android:elevation="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_coin1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_coin2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/seteept" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b_flip1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttondois" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b_flip2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttondois" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Podes clarificar o que fica lento?

Comment: Aplicação tem  duas rodas que giram quando se clica num botão.cada roda tem um botão. Elas ao girar trocam a imagem da roda.. E essa parte que fica lenta.. EM alguns telefones, ao clicar no botão as rodas giram muito lentamente , chegando mesmo a demorar 20 segundos..

Comment: Você pode colocar elas girando dentro de uma trhead, uma para cada, ai desocuparia a main thread e deixaria nas filhas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar threads para cada "roda" que você tem, assim você não rodará elas na main thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,360,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(1000);
            iv_coin1.startAnimation(rotate);
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou tentar assim que tiver tempo ;).

Comment: Assim esta rodar a primeira vez e as outras ja nao roda..

Comment: Tens que implementar a chamada da thread quando você clicar sobre a roda...

Comment: Sou novo nisto nao sei fazer essa parte...